# How to get the "vocal enthusiast" trophy in Dynasty Warriors 8

Tags: achievements, dynasty-warriors-8

The trophy says "listen to all of the voice lines within the gallery". I have to unlock all the lines, first.

I tried beating every stage in story mode, but I unlocked none of the voices. I beat ambition mode, but I still didn't unlock any charcter lines in the gallery. I maxed out my bond with a few characters, and unlocked the inferior and superior lines for only Dang Ai and Zhang Bao.

How do I unlock all the voice lines for the *Vocal Enthusiast* trophy?

Answer (score 1):

Max out all bonds meters (both male and female). For example, max Cao Cao's bond with say, Zhenji (female character) and Cao Pi (male character). Once you've maxed both, you'll unlock all voices corresponding to Cao Cao, automatically.